# Shifting x-axis to the right (metafor, R)

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am working on a forest plot in R using the metafor package and am trying to shift the whole x-axis (alim) to the right to accommodate ilab columns.

Am still not allowed to post images so my current plot now appears as something like this where the text and x-axis overlaps:

```
|ilab text|                                |mean [ci.lb, ci.ub]|
    |---measure values + ci---|
```

And I want something like this

```
|ilab text|                                |mean [ci.lb, ci.ub]|
             |---measure values + ci---|
```

Although the forestplot package seemed to allow this with its graph.pos function, I couldn't seem to find a similar function in metafor.

I have two questions:

1) Is the x-axis position set on default in metafor?

2) Can this default be overwritten, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Wen

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: the key is to adjust the xlim, alim and ilab.xpos parameters in relation to 0 (the start of the x-axis) as a reference point.

For example, if this code gives you an overlap,

```
forest(x, ci.lb = lower, ci.ub = upper,
       xlim = c(-350, 170), xlab = "Proportion (%)", at = c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100),
       alim = c(0, 100),
       ilab = cbind(period, population), ilab.xpos = c(-275, -175), ilab.pos = c(4, 4), cex = 0.75)
```

You can adjust ilab text further to the left of the x axis by adjusting ilab.xpos() values further away from 0 (e.g. from -175 in the above code to -200). This has to be within the limits of your xlim.